# Using CSS to stack two TDs from one TR on top of each other

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to economise on the horizontal space a table uses by stacking two tds from one row on top of each other using CSS?

As a simple visual example, moving from this:

```
Timestamp | User | Country | City | Rating
==========================================
21 Nov    | Bob  | UK      | Bath | 5
------------------------------------------
21 Nov    | Ann  | USA     | NYC  | 3
------------------------------------------
```

...to something like this:

```
Timestamp | User | Country | Rating
          |      | City    |
===================================
21 Nov    | Bob  | UK      | 5
          |      | Bath    |
-----------------------------------
21 Nov    | Ann  | USA     | 3
          |      | NYC     |
-----------------------------------
```

At this point should I be considering using structured DIVs instead of a table? I'd like to stick with a table so that the page is still readable for screen-readers and those with stylesheets disabled.

Comment: You can do something like this with `colSpan` attribute, but it's ugly. You can use two divs, or a `<br>` if it's only simple text lines.

Comment: As @MightyPork said, colspan is pretty ugly and requires you to edit attributes of the markup, and `td` elements aren't really made to be stacked. See http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-table-roundup/ for a discussion of some responsive table tricks. One of those might suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

## [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2U9fL/)

You (kinda) can do this in CSS3, however with a little tricking. This isn't the perfect/beautifulest solution but it is a working one.

When you render the table create a column that contains the two merged columns. Now you can show/hide these columns according to the width of your browser.

This will work only if you want to concatenate not too many columns, because otherwise you will have a very big redundant table, and the mess just becomes bigger if you want to merge already merged columns.

### HTML

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Timestamp</th>
         <th>User</th>
         <th>Country</th>
         <th>City</th>
         <th>Country<br/>City</th>
         <th>Rating</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>21 Nov</td>
         <td>Bob</td>
         <td>Uk</td>
         <td>Bath</td>
          <td>UK<br/>Bath</td>
         <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>21 Nov</td>
         <td>Ann</td>
         <td>USA</td>
         <td>NYC</td>
         <td>USA<br/>NYC</td>
         <td>3</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

### CSS

```
@media screen and (min-width: 500px){
    td:nth-of-type(5), th:nth-of-type(5){
        display: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px){
    td:nth-of-type(3), th:nth-of-type(3), td:nth-of-type(4), th:nth-of-type(4){
        display: none;
    }
}
```